# newDateTime and new DateTime difference, if any

Tags: c#, datetime

In India, the common date format is `dd/MM/yyyy`. So I input into the `TextBox` in Indian format and with the code posted in one of Stack Overflow sites, I am converting `textBox1.Text` to the format of `yyyy/MM/dd` format to further management of the string to find difference between two dates.

Though this code taken from Stack Overflow works fine with my needs, I am at a loss to understand the difference between `new DateTime` and `newDateTime`. Would anyone of you please explain? I appreciate the help.

```
DateTime d1;
if (DateTime.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out d1))
{
    string newDateTime = d1.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mmtt");
    MessageBox.Show(newDateTime.ToString());
}
```

Comment: `new DateTime` means you are creating a new `DateTime` struct and `newDateTime` is a variable.

Comment: Okay. I was confused at that point. Because when I wrote the code in Visual Studio Community, the programme was misbehaving and I lost all semblance of normality and could not understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx) is a constructor that (in this case) attempts to create a specified date format from a string. In it's simplest structure, it is declared like this:

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime (int, int, int);
```

You then have a `string` which is a variable, with the name `newDateTime`. This is simply a string, which holds a collection of characters.

You can *format* a string, as you have done in your example, which would rely on the data being passed in to have some form of structure. However, once the information has been passed in, it is just a string.

Comment: _You can format a string_ Well, technically, you can _format_ a DateTime :)

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing two variable with different data type and structure. Hence `newDateTime` is a string type variable and if your defining DateTime type variables you need to define it like `DateTime dt; or DateTime dt = new DateTime();`  These separate things have its own properties. Check these links

[String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)

[DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Well, I appreciate thre references given.